# How can I turn Tag to List ? or How can I use tags in for loop?(Django)

Tags: django

I want to show some tags product part of the homepage. How can I do with for loop?

That's my index func. can I turn tags in product to list?

I try like : example_tag = Tag.objects.filter('example')

but not working

> ```
> def index(request,):
>
>     category = Category.objects.all
>
>
>     context = {
>         'products': products,
>         'category': category,
>
>     }
>     return render(request, 'index.html', context )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I believe we are missing some information in order to help you out.

I'm assuming you have a `Tag` model and you want to filter the tags.

This won't work:

```py
Tag.objects.filter('example')
```

Because you not telling the ORM by which field you want to filter.

You'll need to do something like this:

```py
Tag.objects.filter(field='example')
```

Are the tags associated with products or categories or both?

Comment: actually I want to use both. I trying in index page like : example have Black Friday. I create black Friday tag and tagging some product. and I want to show index page. I try like this but give this error :
Cannot resolve keyword 'field' into field. Choices are: id, name, product, slug

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want a list-:

```
category=list(Category.objects.filter(field_name="filter").values())
```

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'field' into field. Choices are: id, name, product, slug
this error give :/


trying like : 

def index(request,):

    category = Category.objects.all
    example = list(Tag.objects.filter(field='example').values())

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'category': category,


    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context )

Comment: You need to replace field with the field you want to filter..

Comment: I try like this = but not work :/      def index(request,):

    category = Category.objects.all
    deneme12 = list(Tag.objects.filter(field_name="deneme12").values(6))

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'category': category,
        'deneme12':deneme12,

Comment: Cannot resolve keyword 'field_name' into field. Choices are: id, name, product, slug

Comment: deneme12=list(Tag.objects.filter(name='deneme12').values())

Comment: hii sorry for late :/ I was working. I try like this and trying for look like :{{ for i in deneme12 }}  {{ product.name }}  {{ endfor }} but not working. how can I use for loop here ?

Comment: try this

  {% for product in deneme12 %}
{{product.name}}
{% endfor %}